# Simple RequireJS in node

Tags: windows, node.js, requirejs

I would like to exclusively use RequireJS for node.

I cannot seem to get it all to run in the same file when i run "node r.js file.js":

```
define('a', function () {
    console.log("loaded a");
    return {};
});

require(['a'], function(a){

});
```

is there any way to override define and require strictly with requirejs' definitions.

Also is there a way to do this strictly with r.js and not installing requirejs npm.

Comment: What's wrong with node's module system (and `require`)?

Comment: Not sure how you intend to work with requirejs without requiring the package... Of course you need to require it in Node.js if you want to use it...

Comment: I'm trying to make modules that are usable in the browser as well.  Is there a way that i can require r.js and override require/define?

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use require.js in node!

The require.js documentation [includes a section](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) on installing require with node.js .

- First, you go to the console (assuming you have npm which you should) and type:

  `npm install requirejs`
- After that, you're all set up. First you need to require require (no pun intended), so in the top of your main js file, you need something like:

  `var requirejs = require('requirejs');`
- Then, you can configure it:

  `requirejs.config({/*your config with shims,etc goes here*/});`

That's it! You can now use it:

```
requirejs(["module1","module2"],function(mod1,mod2){
    //whatever here
});
```

There are more detailed instructions on [this page](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html).

#### A better solution to the bigger issue:

You can use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Browserify lets you share code between the client and the server using node.js style `require()` statements. It shims common things for your like `process.nextTick`. It even shims modules like `path`, `events` and even `vm`.

I have personally used it in several production projects and it works.

Comment: Since browserify2, the overhead of the code is absolutely minimal. It basically adds 100 bytes to your code, no more. Compared to require.js which adds 16KB...

Comment: I have certain restrictions that preclude npm install requirejs, on top of which my modules are all using require( expecting requirejs,  I saw this doc and it didn't help as I have browser code that I need to run in node not the other way around.

Comment: @maxfridbe check out the part that says "If you prefer to not use npm, you can get r.js directly:" in the instruction page I linked to. You can run the browser code but you need _one_ other node.js module to require require.js , configure it, and call the rest. Good luck

Comment: I attempted to follow those r.js instructions but kept running into issues (which i know is not super helpful) like I need to keep my web infrastructure 100% the same as browser and not change it to run on node.  My solution atm is to run phantomjs which has no predefined node require to get mangled.